# Serilog with WP8.1

Tags: logging, windows-phone-8.1, serilog

I'm trying to use Serilog in a WP8.1 app. There are no functions like

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
.WriteTo.RollingFile("log-{Date}.txt")
.CreateLogger();
```

when creating the LoggerConfiguration. The only chance to write the log to file is to use WriteTo.TextWriter(...) method, where I have to define my own implementation of the abstract TextWriter class. Is there any possibilities to let Serilog write the log entries to file automaticed (like in desktop apps)?

Thanks